# How can I get my Set top box to work connected to my AP?

Tags: networking, router

I've been reorganising part of my home network - there's physical segment that has several devices, and originally it was laid out like this. The switch is a 'dumb' switch - a [linksys SE 2500](https://www.linksys.com/support-product?sku=SE2500), and the current AP is a [Mercusys MR70X](https://www.mercusys.com/sg/product/details/mr70x/). The set top box is a Tatung 3102

All devices here are connected via *wired* ethernet to the next device down the chain - an android TV, a windows HTPC and a set top box provided by my ISP, singtel. I'm not sure of the exact model.

[image]

I upgraded my AP to (the current) one with more ethernet ports and decided to eliminate the switch.

I moved the TV, HTPC and set top box over to the AP from the switch (which is unconnected) and the 'main' link from the ONR as per the manufacturer's instructions (so uplink to the WAN port, 3 devices on their own ports).

[image]

I noticed that the HTPC has a different IP (odd) and the set top box is unable to connect. More precisely, its says its connected then gets stuck on this screen [image], the time starts on the clock display on the STB from 12:00 and dosen't correct itself like it has a normal/correct connection.

Putting the switch back gets things back to normal. I'd *like* to eliminate the switch if possible.

There's [mentions of vlans](https://netgearstore.sg/blogs/knowledge-base/orbi-singtel-tv-vlan-tag) being used for TV connections for other routers but - would a vlan tag 'just' pass through a dumb switch, and can I configure my AP to do the same thing?

Comment: https://goughlui.com/2018/08/17/tested-vlans-in-the-home-through-dumb-switches/ seems to indicate vlans do pass through which might explain why the former topology works, and why the ISP in question gives 'dumb' switches when there's more than one STB in a unit. It dosen't quite fit in the question (yet) but this might be handy later.

Comment: I don't actually see how VLANs would exist in your former topology. Dot1Q VLAN is a L2 capability, which must be configured. An unconfigurable switch isn't VLAN-aware, and I don't think you've configured the interfaces in your TV or STB either :-) The only device there that's certainly capable of tagging Ethernet frames is the MR70x, and even then it will only send tagged frames if configured to do so. It uses VLANs internally for QoS prioritization - you'd want your IPTV or VoIP traffic to have higher priority as they suffer from latency, jabbering, jitter etc., bursty std traffic does not.

Comment: What comes to ISP giving dumb switches on multi-STB implementations - they do it because they're dirt cheap, and provide rudimentary traffic isolation. You don't want the stream of The Big Game you're watching to be interrupted by frames belonging to your kid's simultaneous Lego Movie stream. Otherwise - does the simulator interface at https://www.mercusys.com/sg/download/mr70x (password admin) look the same as your router's interface?

Comment: @Peregrino69 looks right to me - it's identical to what I see.

Comment: OK. Unfortunately the sim only shows the Router mode (AP mode link is borked), but as you're connecting the devices directly I'd assume that's what you're using anyway. I'd start by connecting the STB alone to the router, then checking under DHCP Server if it receives a lease, and what info does System - System log show. Both are under Advanced.

Comment: I recall that it had gotten a lease (from the AP UI). There's some other STB related oddness I really should add to the question too. I'll see if I can poke at it in a day or two

Comment: What's the STB itself?

Comment: Updated based on https://www.singtel.com/content/dam/singtel/personal/support/self-collect-(popstation)/Set%20Top%20Box.pdf that its a Tatung 3102. I'll confirm when I can poke at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142790/discussion-between-peregrino69-and-journeyman-geek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mercusys simulator](https://www.mercusys.com/sg/download/mr70x) shows this LAN port configuration:

[image]

This is most likely the default state. Assuming the STB was on failure situation connected to LAN3, just disabling 802.1Q tag should resolve the issue.

Theory behind:

VLANs are in this device used for traffic prioritization. The default priority is 3, used for standard traffic along with 0. 1-2 are low, 4-5 mid, 6 and 7 high priority traffic. LAN3 has high priority, intended to be connected to an IPTV system.

Dot1Q VLAN is a L2 technology. It's never on by default, but must be intentionally enabled and configured. Dumb switches aren't VLAN aware and can't be configured. Edge devices like TVs and STBs are also VLAN-unaware, unconfigurable dumb devices. They only communicate using standard Ethernet frames.

The only reason to have dot1Q tagging as an option is to ensure the router sends and expects to receive in ports belonging to a VLAN only frames tagged with the VLAN ID (number). Untagged ingress traffic is simply dropped. Tagged frame is 1522 bytes, while standard frame is 1518 bytes. The STB being a dumb device can't handle the too-large frames so it either drops or mangles them. Hence no connectivity.

When all the devices are connected to the dumb switch, traffic is only flowing with std Ethernet frames. Consequently no issues.

This device isn't actually a full-blown router. It's a switch with limited routing capabilities. Another option to resolve the situation is disabling VLANs altogether. This makes it behave like a dumb switch - the traffic between the 3 LAN ports and the WiFi is switched, only traffic between the LAN and the WAN segments will be routed. If VLANs are enabled but dot1Q tag disabled, the device will still internally forward the traffic according to the set priorities.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCk3d.png these settings seem to do the trick - its a little different from what you suggested

Comment: Cool! So the culprit was the dot1Q tag?

Comment: Those options weren't even there, just had to set the port in question for IPTV

Comment: Aha. It's great that mfg:s offer simulators. Greater still if they were accurate. Anyway I'm glad I was able to help you on with this :-)

Comment: Well, it got me looking at the right place - [the manual](https://static.mercusys.com/manual/1910080056_MR70X_UG_REV1.0.0_V320210819112001.pdf) - digital only is probably a better source, and there's stuff that's not there either